# filter based on created column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to filter data based on a column I'm create locally by extracting data from a substring. The string contains a date in the middle of a bunch of other info e.g. "Transaction date: 2/9/2023 12:00:00 AM, Cash in: 0.00, Cash out: 10,100.00, Owner name: " I want to add a column with that date and use that column to filter for the dates I'm interested in.

I got the date extracted and returned in a column using the below, but I can't use that column to filter

```
select CAST(SUBSTRING(strvalue,19,CHARINDEX(' ',strvalue,19)-CHARINDEX(' ',strvalue,16)) as date) as DateCreated,
        null as DateChecked,
        null as DateConfirmed,
        strIDRef as CTR 

    from dbo.tblModificationLog
    inner join dbo.tblProcessLog on dbo.tblModificationLog.intProcLogID = dbo.tblProcessLog.intProcLogID
    WHERE strContextObjID = 'CTR' 
        and strProcess = 'CTR report deleted'
```

I tried to filter on that column by using

```
select *
from (
    select CAST(SUBSTRING(strvalue,19,CHARINDEX(' ',strvalue,19)-CHARINDEX(' ',strvalue,16)) as date) as DateCreated,
        null as DateChecked,
        null as DateConfirmed,
        strIDRef as CTR 

    from dbo.tblModificationLog
    inner join dbo.tblProcessLog on dbo.tblModificationLog.intProcLogID = dbo.tblProcessLog.intProcLogID
    WHERE strContextObjID = 'CTR' 
        and strProcess = 'CTR report deleted'
        ) l
where DateCreated >='2024-01-01'
```

and I'm getting the following

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Note: I know the right solution is to split the string into different columns in the database, but I don't have the ability to do that. I'm working with read only access to a database designed and managed by a company that seems to exist for the sole purpose of making my job miserable. Every string starts with " Transaction date: dd/mm/yyyy 12:00:00 AM". I've reviewed the output of the column I'm creating when I use just the first block of code, and it consists entirely of valid dates. the only change between that and the second block is the addition of selecting based on the new column.

I've checked the supposedly similar questions, but they don't at all address the issue I'm having.

Comment: "The string contains a date in the middle of a bunch of other info"   Please share (the contents) of that string.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @Luuk Transaction date: 10/4/2023 12:00:00 AM, Cash in: 11,323.00, Cash out: 11,323.00, Owner name:

Comment: Mistake #1: putting multiple pieces of info in the same column, especially without a well-defined syntax. Split these into separate columns (when you insert from the application). Use JSON if you *really* have to.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't be storing dates in the middle of a string, and should be storing them in a date (and time) data type. Why not fix your design? Then you *can't* have this problem.

Comment: @Charlieface I didn't create that column and I don't have the authority needed to clean it up. I'm working with read only access, so I'm pretty limited in what I can do

Comment: Use `NULLIF` on the `CHARINDEX` to null out `0`. And use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` in case you can't convert it.

Comment: We need a [mre], not just one record which happens to work with what your did, like https://dbfiddle.uk/ya-0bf31, because the problem is in one of the other records....